# converting mean iou and dice coefficient to tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am a beginner in tensorflow, and found working of IOU and Dice Coefficient working from kaggle, but it is written in tf1 and I need it to convert to tf2.

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

def mean_iou(y_true, y_pred):
    prec = []
    for t in np.arange(0.5, 1.0, 0.05):
        y_pred_ = tf.to_int32(y_pred > t)
        score, up_opt = tf.metrics.mean_iou(y_true, y_pred_, 2, y_true)
        K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        with tf.control_dependencies([up_opt]):
            score = tf.identity(score)
        prec.append(score)
    return K.mean(K.stack(prec), axis=0)

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
```

I changed a few things to make it tf2 compatible but i am not able to resolve the issue

```
def mean_iou(y_true, y_pred):
    prec = []
    for t in np.arange(0.5, 1.0, 0.05):
        y_pred_ = tf.cast(y_pred > t, dtype = tf.int32)
        score, up_opt = tf.compat.v1.metrics.mean_iou(y_true, y_pred_, 2)
        tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session().run(tf.compat.v1.local_variables_initializer())
        with tf.control_dependencies([up_opt]):
            score = tf.identity(score)
        prec.append(score)
    return tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.mean(tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.stack(prec), axis=0)

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype = tf.float32)
    y_true_f = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.flatten(y_true)
    print(y_true_f)
    y_pred_f = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.flatten(y_pred)
    print(y_pred_f)
    intersection = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.sum(y_true_f) + tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
```

*RuntimeError: in user code:
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
return step_function(self, iterator)
:6 mean_iou  *
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session().run(tf.compat.v1.local_variables_initializer())
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:641 get_session  **
session = _get_session(op_input_list)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:601 _get_session
raise RuntimeError('Cannot get session inside Tensorflow graph function.')*

**RuntimeError: Cannot get session inside Tensorflow graph function.**

**I am using keras with it, so I won't be needing anything like session so if anyone could help me in converting it to normal keras.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow @tf.function - Cannot get session inside Tensorflow graph function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968096/tensorflow-tf-function-cannot-get-session-inside-tensorflow-graph-function)

Comment: @papaya no it doesn't, the error is same though.

Comment: The first `dice_coef` should work in tensorflow 2.

Comment: @jakub what about mean_iou? I am unable to solve the above error

Comment: @Kazama have you found a solution to rewrite it for tf2? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This was an implementation I used for the mean_iou without the session. When passing this function to metrics in the model compile step I pass it with parentheses, like `model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=[mean_iou()])`.

Not sure about the dice coefficient but will update here if I figure out a solution.

```
class mean_iou():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name__ = 'mean_iou'
        self.m_iou = tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=2) 

    def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred):
        prec = []
        for t in np.arange(0.5, 1.0, 0.05):
            y_pred_ = tf.cast(y_pred > t, dtype=tf.int32)
            self.m_iou.update_state(y_true, y_pred_)
            score = self.m_iou.result()
            prec.append(score)

        return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.stack(prec), axis=0)
```